# How to route dynamically with react-navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

So I am using Version `3.1.4` of `react-navigation`. I have a dynamic Tree that I would like to implement with navigation. I belive every node in my tree would be a button where user would able to click on it and will navigate to next node. So at any given time ,this is how my random Tree node "Folder A" looks like:

```
Folder A
 -> Folder 23
 -> Folder 54
    -> Folder B1
       -> Folder X.1
         -> Folder Data detail screen.
 -> Folder 64
Folder B
-> Folder XYZ
......
```

I know that currently react-navigation [does not support dynamic navigation.](https://react-navigation.canny.io/feature-requests/p/dynamic-routes-for-navigators) and its in a list of feature requests.

So my question is how can I currently built this kind of Tree with react-navigation ? If react-navigation can not do it , are there any other well maintained library that I can use? I did some research about react-native-navigation as well but I could not able to find it if it supports dynamic navigation or not.

Comment: You don't necessarrily need those dynamic routes if your views are the same, only showing different data. 

When you traverse from folder to folder view you'd be staying on the same route, only load different data in your state manager (e.g. `Redux`) and display that.
`Folder Data detail screen` can be one more route, so 2 in total.

Comment: Hey @Davion. Thank you for the reply. I am sorry I just saw your comment. Yeah I am currently using that approach for some use cases. But for some of the other unique cases I have a totally different data set so inner screen has to be different. Not sure how I can achieve it right now.

Comment: You can either introduce a 2nd sub-route (Details Screen 1 and Details Screen 2), or you can create 2 different DetailScreen containers which you'd switch on a singe sub-route. 

I can't say for sure as I'd need to dig a bit into the actual code.